# php login script doesn't do anything (Dreamweaver generated)

Tags: php

I have a working php server and mysql database. Used Dreamweaver to generate a login script but it doesn't work, after hitting submit it reloads the current page. Either way, in success or failure it should change pages. Any ideas?

I solved it, needed to make sure the id and class of the input were different. Once different it worked.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/Connection.php'); ?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['emailField'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['emailField'];
  $password=$_POST['passwordField'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "main.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "login_failed.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_Connection, $Connection);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT email, password FROM customer WHERE email=%s AND password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $Connection) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>

<form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" METHOD="POST" name="login">
       <input type="text" id="emailField" class="emailField" />
     <input type="password" id="passwordField" class="passwordField" />
       <input type="submit" id="sendButton" value="Send" class="sendButton" />
      </form>

CONNECTION.PHP
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_Connection = "localhost";
$database_Connection = "db";
$username_Connection = "test";
$password_Connection = "password";
$Connection = mysql_pconnect($hostname_Connection, $username_Connection, $password_Connection) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Comment: Is the accesscheck GET variable set?

Comment: Show us your Connection.php page.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. As you can tell I'm new to php. Is there a specific place I should look for it?

Also added the connection.php

Comment: You can see if it has any value by checking if you have any accesscheck on your query string - something like http://www.yourdomain.com/login.php?accesscheck=otherpage.php.

Comment: Sorry again, but I did that localhost_Domain/index.php?accesscheck=main.php and it just returned to the index, is this what is supposed to happen. Main.php is the access granted page.

Comment: I made it so that $_GET['accesscheck'] would be a value in one of the text fields, and it was empty. So what should accesscheck be equal to or set to?

Comment: SOLVED: THE ID AND CLASS WERE THE SAME NAME. ONCE CHANGED TO DIFFERENT NAMES IT WORKS

Comment: @John: That doesn't really make sense... You had no `name` attributes in your inputs...

Answer (score 0):

Is **$loginFormAction** not set ?

Can you send us HTML codes of this page ?

Comment: Other than the normal stuff that's it... 
$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Comment: Ah, other than the form data I included everything thing else is standard. When I look at the source code the $loginFormAction is the page (ACTION="index.php"). Hope that answers the question, sorry I'm quite rusty.

Comment: still have the problem, that's just what the php generates... Damn I suck at this.

Answer (score 0):

@John: Try --

```
<form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" METHOD="POST" name="login">
    <input type="text" name="emailField" id="emailField" class="emailField" />
    <input type="password" name="passwordField" id="passwordField" class="passwordField" />
    <input type="submit" id="sendButton" value="Send" class="sendButton" />
</form>
```